# How to import dbpedia data into arangodb for use in a django website?

Tags: python, django, arangodb, dbpedia

I'm new to programming and just learnt python and some django basics. I want to build a website to display wikipedia data in a particular format and also display the connections using plotly dash. However i'm unable to find instructions on how to import dbpedia data into arango db so as to store objects/entities as documents with attributes and map the graph of relationships. Something like relfinder on dbpedia website, offering more info along with it.

Is it possible to first setup arango db in django and then use sparql querying with python to build my own dataset according to requirements? If yes, please provide some instructions or link some resources with info on how to do it.

Is there any other way I could achieve this in an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You could [download the full DBpedia dataset](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets), load it to your Arango instance, and work from there.

Note that the current public DBpedia endpoint holds the 2016-10 dataset; the 2019-08-30 dataset is still a work in progress.

There are many other alternatives, which dive deep into opinion, and aren't appropriate to this site.